# Adding image to existing collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a sample app of StudentRecord in which i have a `UICollectionview` of student's images. I want to add button to last cell and this button should add student's image to the last cell.
Following is my existing code, how to modify it-

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;
    long row = [indexPath row];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:studentImages[row]];

    myCell.imageView.image = image;



    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: on Button Clickevent or last cell DidSelect event you can add one more data in existing array and reload your collectionview that add one more record

Comment: yes this can be helpful!! i should go by button clickevent